# How to use addClass and removeClass repeatedly on a single element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So what I want to achieve is just change the classes of a HTML link on every click like this:

- Remove **.first** class if it is present, then add **.second** class
- Remove **.second** class if it is present, then add **.third** class
- Remove **.third** class if it is present, then add **.fourth** class
- And so forth...

No luck so far. What could I be doing wrong?

Here's the single line of HTML code where I'm trying my jQuery code on:

```
<a class="first" href="#">Test 1</a>
```

Here's my jQuery:

```
$( "#menu li a.first" ).click(function() {

   $( "#menu li a.first" ).removeClass("first").addClass("second");

}

$( "#menu li a.second" ).click(function() {

   $( "#menu li a.second" ).removeClass("second").addClass("third");

}

$( "#menu li a.third" ).click(function() {

   $( "#menu li a.second" ).removeClass("third").addClass("fourth");

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can identify it with id and then check it with hasClass() function of jquery

Comment: As noobish as this may sound but I'm new to this. Can you show me a demo?

Comment: You have missing `)` in your code for each function

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The problem is you're trying to attach the event handler before it even has the class `second` or `third`.

Besides this approach is pretty verbose. I suggest simply providing an array of classes. Like so:

```
var classNames = ['first', 'second', 'third'];
```

Then add a different identifier to the button, for instance add a class `class-changer`. And attach the following event handler.

```
$('.class-changer').on('click', function() {
    var $el = $(this)
    for (var i= 0; i < classNames.length; i++) {
        if ($el.hasClass(classNames[i]) && classNames[i+1]) {
           $el.removeClass(classNames[i]).addClass(classNames[i+1]);
           break;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: There is a small bug in that for loop. This will skip the middle class and go straight from 'first' to 'thrid'. Add a break; inside the if block and it should work.

Answer (score 10):

Put all classes in an array and on click of the link add class one by one like following.

```js
var classes = ["first", "second", "third", "fourth"];
$("#menu li a").click(function () {
    var index = classes.indexOf(this.className);
    var newIndex = (index + 1) % classes.length; //return to first after reaching last

    $(this).removeClass(classes[index]).addClass(classes[newIndex]);
});
```

```css
.first { color: red; }
.second { color: green; }
.third { color: blue; }
.fourth { color: purple; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu">
    <li>
        <a class="first" href="#">Test 1</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with the usage of `.data()`

HTML:

```
<a class="first" href="#" id="test">Test 1</a>
```

JS:

```
$(".first").data("classes",["one","two","three","four"]).click(function() {
  var elem = $(this);
  var cnt = (elem.data("cnt") || 0)
  var classes = elem.data("classes");
  elem.removeClass().addClass(classes[cnt % classes.length] + " first").data("cnt",++cnt);
});
```

### Demo

```js
$(".first").data("classes",["one","two","three","four"]).click(function() {
  var elem = $(this);
  var cnt = (elem.data("cnt") || 0)
  var classes = elem.data("classes");
  elem.removeClass().addClass(classes[cnt % classes.length] + " first").data("cnt",++cnt);
});
```

```css
.one{
  color:red;
}
.two{
  color:yellow;
}
.three{
  color:green;
}
.four{
  color:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="first" href="#" id="test">Test 1</a>
```

Comment: You should not calculate 3 times the `$(this)`. This solution could be improved a lot, maybe you could make a post in codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: YMMV, but... You could JSLint to see that you're not putting semicolons in all lines. You could do `.data("cnt", cnt+1)` instead of increment a variable which is then discarded. You could remove the current class and add the new one, instead of removing all current classes and re-adding the two that you want. You could write the code in a more elegant way, less complex to read, and easier to maintain; one improvement would be not to put 3 instructions on the same line.

Comment: @ANeves Extremely sorry mate if anything that I spoke hurts you. Actually I am a non native english speaker. This happens with most of the people here in SO. Sorry :)

Comment: No worries, thanks; I respect your 36k, I know how much time-spent-helping they mean. :)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you actually only have 1 link whose state you're trying to change, instead of a bunch of links in your menu that you want to ALL be moved from ".first" to ".second" when one is clicked, I would suggest [this](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/#using-the-triggering-element) as the most idiomatic way (pun not intended).

```
// Only select the menu once
var $menu = $('#menu');

// Delegate to elements with the correct class.
// Specifying the "li a" is probably unnecessary,
// unless you have other elements with the same classes in "#menu".
$menu.on('click', '.first', function(e) {

    // Inside a jQuery event handler,
    // `this` refers to the element that triggered the event.
    // If the event is delegated, it's the delegation target
    // (".first" in this instance), not the bound element ("#menu").
    $(this).removeClass('first').addClass('second');

});

$menu.on('click', '.second', function(e) {
   $(this).removeClass('second').addClass('third');
});

$menu.on('click', '.third', function(e) {
   $(this).removeClass('third').addClass('fourth');
});
```

Resources:

- [Why should you cache jQuery selectors?](http://docs.sitefinity.com/for-developers-cache-results-from-your-jquery-selectors)
- [Event Delegation in jQuery](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)
- ["this" in jQuery events](https://learn.jquery.com/events/inside-event-handling-function/)
- [General jQuery Optimization](https://24ways.org/2011/your-jquery-now-with-less-suck/)

Comment: I like this one. The best answer could be something in between this and Azim's solution.

Comment: Solutions like Azim's or GMchris's are necessary for larger apps that actually need to optimize event handler memory size, or for more complicated functionality (where the array of classNames might be an arbitrary size or something), but IMO, **for this specific case**, they're just more complicated for little gain.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this would solve your issue but I would shoot for a conditional statement and only one **delegated** event listener:

```js
$("#menu li").on("click", "a", function () {
  if ($(this).hasClass("first")) {
    $(this).removeClass("first").addClass("second");
  } else if ($(this).hasClass("second")) {
    $(this).removeClass("second").addClass("third");
  }
  // etc...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to bind an event the selected element must exist previously.

To bind an event handler to elements that does not yet exist (ex. dynamically created or modified) you can do this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#menu li a.first', function() {

    $( "#menu li a.first" ).removeClass("first").addClass("second");

});

$(document).on('click', '#menu li a.second', function() {

   $( "#menu li a.second" ).removeClass("second").addClass("third");

});

$(document).on('click', '#menu li a.third', function() {

   $( "#menu li a.third" ).removeClass("third").addClass("fourth");

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a class="changable first" href="#">Test 1</a>
$( ".changable" ).click(function(event) {
classes = ['first','second','third','fourth']
changed=false
for (c in classes){
    if (event.target.classList.contains(classes[c]) && changed==false){
       $(this).removeClass((classes[c]));
       index_to_add=classes.indexOf(classes[c])+1
       class_to_add=classes[index_to_add]
       $(this).addClass(class_to_add);
       changed=true;
    }
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Okay so there is a few workaround for this, which wasn't mentioned yet.

You can use Javascript object for this not just array. Object could make it easier if you want a chain instead of list.

```
var classNames = {first:'second', second:'third', third:'fourth'};

$('#menu li a').on('click', function() {
    if(typeof classNames[this.className] !== 'undefined'){
        this.className = classNames[this.className];
    }
});
```

Second method is to use `.on('click', [selector], handler)` instead `click` which can handle dynamicly loaded, added or changed elements.

```
$('#menu li').on('click', 'a.first', function() {
    $(this).removeClass("first").addClass("second");
});

$('#menu li').on('click', 'a.second', function() {
   $(this).removeClass("second").addClass("third");
});

$('#menu li').on('click', 'a.third', function() {
   $(this).removeClass("third").addClass("fourth");
});
```

Not even close to perfect but still a working solution.

You can use `if .. else` or `switch .. case` inside a function to create a decision tree.

So basically there is a lot of solution. Pick the best.

Answer (score 0):

Try binding event to parent,

My try,

```js
var $classes = ['first', 'second', 'third'];

$(function(){
    $('#subject').click(function(){
        current = $(this).find('a:first');
        index = $.inArray(current.attr('class'), $classes);
        if($classes.length > index+1)
            current.removeClass($classes[index]).addClass($classes[index+1])
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='subject'>
 <a class="first" href="#">Test 1</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

No, you can't. As JavaScript only runs after the page loads ( if you put them inside the `$( document ).ready()` function ), further functions down below **will never be executed**. It can only detect the `<a class="first" href="#">Test 1</a>` but not the `<a class="second" href="#">Test 1</a>` because the `<a class="second" href="#">Test 1</a>` are generated after the page loads and, therefore, will never be executed, unless you are using Ajax.

**Update:** This can be done. Please see @i3b13's comment below.

Comment: Not completely true. In jQuery you can use `.on('click', [selector], handler)` to handle clicks on dynamicly loaded, added or changed elements.

Comment: Yeah, I just see the other answers and they work, this is another great solution to learn for me today. Thanks @i3b13

Comment: @I3B13 cool - could you make this an answer? This is a different approach, which may help future readers while all current answers just pack all logic into a single method